# Open file coming from an invoke request on Blackberry 10 Cascades

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am writing a Blackberry 10 Cascades app. I am trying to open a file which is an email attachment.

```
int in_fd = open(m_uri.replace("file://","").toUtf8().constData(), O_RDONLY);
```

(There's a reason I am using the open() call)

But the file cannot be opened. I understand that this is to do with sandboxing and app permissions, and that the Invocation framework can make a copy of the file in the target app's directory. What I can't figure out is how to get the path to that file so that I can open it.

I need to know:

- How to make sure the Invocation Framework copies the file to my apps sandbox on invocation.
- How to access the resulting copied file.
- In C++

Answer (score 0):

Can you print an example of what is contained inside m_uri when your code runs?

If the path you are feeding open() does not have a leading /, then it will look from the app's home directory which is not what you want.